# Add a link to the reason/explanation for a dismiss notification

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Whenever I see a new notification of some kind (e.g. 'no more than one @user can be notified'), there is a message of the notification and a close message.

Could we also have a link inside the 'dismiss' box to an explanation of what the notification is about; why there is such a policy?  i.e. more info, as the 'dismiss' notification itself necessarily doesn't say much.

For instance, with the 'no more than one @user', the first time I saw that, it just irritated me and seems arbitrary and not very helpful (moreover, in my view an example of the various half-solutions to a SO-deisgn 'problem'.)  If a link is provided I can go and read around it and understand what the policy is and why.

Otherwise I have to guess a question to ask on the relvant meta- site that may provide hints to the answer.

Comment: So you just want to insert a small link to information like this: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)?

Comment: Yes, something exactly of that form, relevant to the particular notification.